# Scene is created two times in Corona

Tags: coronasdk, transition, scene, corona-storyboard

I am using storyboard in corona sdk. My motto is to go from one state of screen to another and then return to the same state of first screen. So while i transited from first to second and neither purge the scene nor remove it from the memory. But when I go back to again first scene its create function is called again, although the first scene is in memory.

Comment: create is called again, or enterscene?

Comment: Do you have the autopurge turned on? (storyboard.purgeOnSceneChange = true)?  Could you be running low on memory which would trigger a purge in the background?

Answer (score 0):

if you do storyboard.gotoScene("previousone") from the second scene and getting a new 'previous' scene then:

1. you might have auto purge on

   (storyboard.purgeOnSceneChange == true)
2. you might be getting memory warning on runtime - you can check it with this code:

   local function handleLowMemory( event )
       print( "memory warning received!" )
   end

   Runtime:addEventListener( "memoryWarning", handleLowMemory )